# How do I display a default value when no suggestion found in suggestbox

Tags: gwt, suggestbox

I would like to display a default value (that I already set using setDefaultSuggestionsFromText()) when there is no suggestion displayed for the user entered value. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You need a `SuggestOracle` that always returns a suggestion. You could easily build one that wraps your current `SuggestOracle` and returns your canned suggestion when the wrapped oracle returns none.